# URLs, even when containing http://, aren't always automatically hyperlinked

Tags: bug, status-declined, hyperlinks

When I try writing more than one URL without anything but a space between them, although they contain http://, the second one doesn't get hyperlinked.

**Here are a few examples:**

1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ - the second URL is not automatically hyperlinked, but you can click the first and the third ones, so the second one worked as a divider between the first and the third links.
2. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
3. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ -- every link works, because there's something (in this case a comma) between them.

Comment: No problem, Moayad.

Comment: [It seems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/108147#108147) this was fixed. (So, editing this very question would fix the links, but I don't want to change history. Well, just in case: [a screenshot made just now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pka9f.png), last edited early 2010.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the auto-hyperlink code uses consuming regexes to detect characters on either side.

When you express links like:

```
http://www.example.com http://example.com
```

The space after the first link is consumed by the match, and not available for the next link, so it fails to match.

Anyway, since it should be EXCEEDINGLY unusual to have multiple bare/naked/unformatted URLs on the same line, I don't think this is worth fixing.

Plus if you really want this just use the proper markup..

```
<http://www.example.com> <http://example.com>
```

Shown below:

http://www.example.com http://example.com

Answer (score 16):

**Solution:** Stop spamming undescribed links in your questions and answers.

If you have multiple links, give other people the courtesy of giving them descriptive text so that people have some idea of what they might be instead of just listing off URLs one after the other.

Answer (score 10):

Works with 2 spaces.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Good suggestion. +1

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to fix it yourself, as [the markdown parser has been open sourced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33867/server-side-markdown-parser-open-sourced-for-bugfixes) ;-)

Comment: You fix it for me. It's easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can bunch all the links into 1 using [LinkBunch](http://linkbun.ch/)

Comment: This service has stopped, I'm afraid.

Comment: oooh. Let me find out more if this is a temporary glitch @Arjan