# Require link text for hyperlinks in questions and answers by disabling automatic hyperlinking of bare URLs

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, auto-linking

This feature request is partially a response to the following: [URL inside parenthesis are not automatically hyperlinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99904/162705).

I propose requiring link text for all hyperlinks in questions and answers (and by extension, not converting bare URLs into hyperlinks). [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153008/cody-gray) makes the following case for using link text instead of bare URLs (emphasis is mine).

> The problem [in which bare URLs between parentheses are not
>   automatically converted into hyperlinks] solves itself if you don't
>   post bare URLs. Make the link text *explanatory.* **Showing us where the
>   link goes is what tooltips are for.**
>
> There are very few cases where bare URLs make sense, and in those few
>   cases, you could use the "workaround" of creating a hyperlink with the
>   URL as the link text.

Note that this would only apply to

- questions and answers (not comments)
- links outside of the Stack Exchange network (as [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [has pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99955/require-link-text-for-hyperlinks-in-questions-and-answers-by-disabling-automatic/99957#99957), "bare links automatically get descriptions if the links are within the SE Network")

Comment: Does this also apply to comments?  Because I often just cut and paste Urls when I want the OP to look at them and don't have time to do anything else (comments are throwaway anyway).

Comment: @Robert: Good point. This would probably just be for questions and answers. Also, although I said that it is a response to [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99904/162705), I didn't intend for it to only apply to URLs inside parentheses.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with applying it to comments, only questions/answers. The distinction is a relative straightforward one, as comments already use the somewhat different mini-markdown syntax.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the original title better matched the behaviour that this is a request to remove, actually.

Comment: I updated the title to be a compromise between my original and Robert's edit. Feel free to adjust it further if necessary. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you guys are missing something: *bare links automatically get descriptions if the links are within the SE Network.*

Example: [Require link text for hyperlinks in questions and answers by disabling automatic hyperlinking of bare URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99955/102937)

Another example, from Stack Overflow: [How can I filter a DataSource before applying it to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837870/in-c-how-can-i-filter-a-datasource-before-applying-it-to-a-listview)

Well, I think it would be cooler to pull the text from the `<title>` element of the hyperlink's target page, and paste that as the description on the bare link.

Comment: Good point. I guess this would apply for any site other than the one on which the question is asked?

Comment: @Chris: Well, I think it would be cooler to pull the text from the `<title>` element of the hyperlink's target page, and paste that as the description on the bare link. :D

Comment: That would definitely be one cool way to handle bare URLs. Could you add that to your answer so that people can vote on it?

Comment: I just noticed that bare links do not get descriptions automatically in comments. Is this by design?