# Bare site links don't lazily turn into nice links on Enterprise

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, so-enterprise

When posting on a Stack Exchange Q&A site, any links to other posts in the network are auto-magically turn into a human-readable links.

For example, this…

> http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99955/98786

becomes this…

> [Require link text for hyperlinks in questions and answers by disabling automatic hyperlinking of bare URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99955/require-link-text-for-hyperlinks-in-questions-and-answers-by-disabling-automatic)`

However, our new [**Stack Overflow Enterprise product**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/98786) does not seem to support that feature.

Is there a reason that feature cannot be supported, or is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the Enterprise product?

Comment: So anyone who buy the Enterprise will be able to submit such bug reports (and feature requests), or only the system used internally by SE employees?

Comment: @ShadowWizard These Meta support sites can be used by anyone with questions, bug reports, or feature requests for any of our products, even they're not public-facing.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, can you also please edit the [tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/enterprise/info)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard done,

Comment: Why wasn't this link prettified on this question?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337034/my-question-was-deleted-for-being-opinion-based-even-though-i-indicated-replies  Is it broked?

Comment: @Won't: Because the question at the other end of the link is deleted?

Comment: Aaah, that's a good excuse.  Thanks.