# URLs in parenthesis do not become links

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL inside parenthesis are not automatically hyperlinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/url-inside-parenthesis-are-not-automatically-hyperlinked)

For example if I do: (http://www.google.com) It does **not** become a link.

But if I do http://www.google.com it works fine.

*Other Examples that work (but in a hacky way):*

- ( http://www.google.com) - Looks like: `( http://www.google.com)`
- (http://www.google.com) - Looks like: `([http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com))`
- (http://www.google.com) - Looks like: `([http://www.google.com][1])` (then somewhere on the post: `[1]: http://www.google.com`)

Why do we need all of these hacky ways to make a link in parenthesis?

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), and if so why?

And if not, this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

*Similar probably duplicate question:* [URL inside parenthesis are not automatically hyperlinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99904/155556)

Comment: @TimStone hehe that is in my question :-P just noticed that now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is actually to place angled brackets around the URL to turn the text into links. In the [original Markdown specifications](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink), users would have to add in the angled brackets manually, but SO does auto-linkification, which is more user friendly.

Your link would look like

> (http://www.google.com)

In code:

```
(<http://www.google.com>)
```

Comment: Fine... but that is just another hack.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It's not a hack - it's how Markdown is **suppose** to work. The fact that most links are automatically processed is just something SO adds to make things easier.