# Searching within my posts feels more limited than expected

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When using the `user:` search operator, search disregards all non-tag content from the question when the post that I own is an answer. This is perhaps better explained with an example.

If I want to find [this answer I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/url-inside-parenthesis-are-not-automatically-hyperlinked/99908#99908), I can perform a tag-based `user:me` search which will work:

> [`user:150235 [bug][auto-linking]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A150235+%5Bbug%5D%5Bauto-linking%5D)

However, the following search will not:

> [`user:150235 parenthesis`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A150235+parenthesis)

This is because I didn't use "parenthesis" in my answer. It is, however, in the question's title, so I would still expect my answer to come up as a result, and I believe that the old search implementation would agree.

From the logic side of things, I can understand why using the `user:` operator might be me saying "I don't want to search in the post body of content I didn't post", but it seems like it should at least incorporate the question's title when looking at answers*.

<sup>*Well, at least in this specific case. Now that search shows questions and answers separately, I can see why this would be problematic (and the current behaviour intentional) in the general case.</sup>

Comment: Just updating: we're not ignoring this, it's on my list to look at after the move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been corrected...when searching within a specific user's posts, titles are now searched on answers as well.