# Is it possible to search my own topics?

Tags: support, search

I mean the topics which I have started. That is, whole topics, not my posts only.

For example, a situation when someone answers my question some time ago, but since then I have forgotten the whole thing, but remember some words from that answer. I could spend a day walking across my posts. Also I know that I can put a filter for particular user, here `user:me`, but in this case I would only find my text.

The situation that arose here so I'm asking this is that I remember someone answering for a unrelated question gave me a tip of useful GCC parameters additional to `-Wall`. I didn't asked for it so *I don't know in what topic to look for* it and who was that. Now I must search all my topics for this keyword, but exclude my own writing.

Comment: With a username like yours, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+rsk82+gcc+wall+-newest). But for others, this is indeed much harder!

Comment: Likely related: [Searching within my posts feels more limited than expected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the post you're looking for is older than 7 days you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). For example this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/534139?search=database&UserId=393087) will search the Q/A pairs you participated in for a given word.

```sql
;with allQs as 
(
    select coalesce(parentid,id) as postid
    from posts p
    where owneruserid = ##userid:int?393087##
) 
select id as [Post Link]
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
from posts p
inner join allQs q on q.postid = p.parentid 
where p.body like '%' + ##search:string?database## +'%'
and p.owneruserid <> ##userid:int?393087##
union
select id as [Post Link]
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
     , creationdate
     , score
from posts p
inner join allQs q on q.postid = p.id
where p.body like '%' + ##search:string?database## +'%'
and p.owneruserid <> ##userid:int?393087##
```

When run today this will be your result:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is only [updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).