# Link rendering different in answer and suggested edit page

Tags: support

I proposed an edit for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256639/463828), where I changed the mark up to make the given url an actual link (when I viewed the answer, I couldn't click the url, because it was not rendered as a link).

My edit got rejected, which is fine, when this edit is too minor (two reviewers marked it as too minor), but another one rejected it with the comment `No actual change, the original has a link.`

When you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2161746), where my edit was rewieved, you can see that the change is only in the markup and the rendered output is the same. So here the url is already rendered as a link, although it's not a link in the mark up.

Why is rendering of this url different in this view from the actual display of the answer? Is it a bug that it is different?

Comment: Or, maybe not in fact. Preview versus rendered output are different which is strange...

Comment: i added the link for you, it's indeed minor but it help to move forward.

Comment: Actually, it probably _is_ a dup of that. The post needed a re-rendering because that post was saved before the bug was fixed. [The same markup works ok now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181300/158667).

Comment: @Frank thanks, sadly I don't get rep now ;)

Comment: @Mat you are right, it seems to work in your example now, I'm just curious if it works on the site as well or just on meta

Comment: @Mat You should post that as an answer; it's exactly correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a leftover from an old bug that has since been fixed:  [URL inside parenthesis are not automatically hyperlinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/url-inside-parenthesis-are-not-automatically-hyperlinked)

The bug still existed when the post was initially saved, and the saved rendered version didn't have the hyperlink due to it.

When the post was re-rendered (in the preview section, and in the edit review pages), now that the bug is fixed, it appeared fine. But not in the question page since the saved rendered version was incorrect, and is not re-rendered in that view.

Any edit on that post would have automagically fixed it.

It is indeed hard to spot by reviewers - they'd have to load the full question view to see that there was indeed a problem with the post.

This is a corner case, and there are a few others of this sort with various effects. The only real "fix" would be to inspect all the pre-rendered posts on the server side each time such a bug is fixed, and re-render when necessary - this seems like too much work for the relatively few cases when it happens.