# Formatting: How to link to an answer on stackoverflow from a question

Tags: support, markdown

I would like to link to an answer in my question. Is there an elegant way to do so?

I'm looking for something like the **tag** short link (applied to answers):

- [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp)

and not something similar to this

- [MAMP: How to upgrade PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375327/mamp-unable-to-upgrade-pear#420953) (this not even indicates that it is a link to an answer...)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375349/420953 (this is what you get when you copy the "link" under a question/answer)
- [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375349/420953) (this is something where you can let your creativity flow...)

Note:

The formatting help

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

should contain this info (if available). It will help to improve content quality.

Answer (score 4):

Below each and every answer you have this:

[image]

Clicking this link you get this box:

[image]

It really can't be any more simple than that.

If you offer to start messing with the post number and have link like `[answer:xxxx]`, it won't be comfortable, clicking the perma-link and copying to clipboard then pasting is faster and better approach in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, it could be more simple! The above yields a short URL that is of no use when used on these SE sites, so needs some little effort before using it! (I [dislike the short URLs a lot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/can-we-please-have-an-easy-way-to-get-the-full-url-to-an-answer).) (Also, for now, this does not automatically get [converted into a clickable, readable title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have#108475). But I guess that will soon change.)

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar with the functionality. for tags a different approach was taken... +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the proper full URL, like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375327/mamp-unable-to-upgrade-pear/8375349#8375349`, [usually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34556/urls-even-when-containing-http-arent-always-automatically-hyperlinked) automatically [gets you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have#108475):

[MAMP: How to upgrade PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375327/mamp-unable-to-upgrade-pear/8375349#8375349)

(Indeed, this is the question title for an answer to that question. This even looks better than [something-like-this](/questions/tagged/something-like-this), if you'd ask me. Also, when manually using Markdown to specify a title, please use the full URL between these sites too, so people can see what a link refers to without clicking it. The referral [does not work](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) between SE sites anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There aren't other ways to link an answer

I don't see a reason to do so. It's comfortable as-is.